# Calling apply to a wrapped (anonymous) function

Tags: javascript, closures

This is probably something stupid, but I have code like this:

```
var f = functionWrapper();
f.apply(this, []);

function functionWrapper() {
    return new function () {
        console.log("Called function");
    }
}
```

Why does it crash and give the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply' test.html:28(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
    return new function () {
```

(which immediately invokes the function as a constructor, and returns the constructed object) to this:

```
    return function () {
```

(which returns the function itself).